# Detect new devices on Network / WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, monitoring

I was on Dual boot and Avast detected a new device on the network and notified me with a popup. I was using a LAN cable, yet it was able to detect the router, my PC and other wireless devices on the network.

Wondering if there is any GUI based tool that can run in the background and keep an eye on new devices getting added to the network. Also, some information about the detected device.

I am using 22.04. Thanks.

Comment: "yet" what do you mean by that? You using a LAN means you are connected to your network so... your router, other pc's, and so on.  "gui based" and "background" are a contradiction and you already have one running. It is called "avahi-daemon", Is "avast" a typo? That is virussoftware for windows. Nothing to do with Ubuntu   See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software) 1 thing: avahi only triggers an event for software to pick up: so a new hard disc is noticed but Nautilus gets a signal that there is something new... Nautilus shows a popup.

Comment: GUI based tools can be minimised to run in the background. Stacer and a lot of Ubuntu tools do that. I was indeed referring to something Avast was providing on my Dual boot Windows 10. Did I miss an answer in your comment?